# Using set in Python inside a loop

Tags: python, dataset

I have the following list in Python:

```
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [4, 6], [2, 7], [3, 9]]
```

I want to group them into `[[1,2,7],[3,4,6,9]]`

My code to do this looks like this:

```
l=[[1, 2], [3, 4], [4, 6], [2, 7], [3, 9]]
lf=[]
for li in l:
    for lfi in lf:
        if lfi.intersection(set(li)):
            lfi=lfi.union(set(li))
            break
    else:
        lf.append(set(li))
```

lf is my final list. I do a loop over l and lf and when I find an intersection between an element from l and another from lf, I would like to merge them (union)

But I can't figure out why this is not working. The first to elements of the list l are being inserted with the append command, but the union is not working. 
My final list lf looks like `[set([1, 2]), set([3, 4])]`

It seems to be something pretty basic, but I'm not familiar with sets. 
I appreciate any help

Thanks

Comment: What do you want the `lf` to be if `l` is `[[1, 2], [3, 4], [4, 6], [2, 7], [3, 9], [3,7]]`? Should it be `[[1,2,7,3,4,6,9]]`? As it stands, the algorithm yields `[set([1, 2, 3, 7]), set([9, 3, 4, 6])]`

Comment: @~unutbu: +1 Good point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
lfi=lfi.union(set(li))
```

You are not modifying the set. You are creating a new set which is then discarded. The original set is still in the `lf` array. Use update instead:

```
lfi.update(li)
```

This modifies the original set instead of creating a new one. The result after making this change:

```
[set([1, 2, 7]), set([9, 3, 4, 6])]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I though that the union behaved like an add, i.e., adding elements to the set, not creating a new one. I did not use add, because it have added the set itself , instead of its elements.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way to write the same thing
For sets,
 `&` means `intersection`
 `|=` means `update`

I have also used `map(set,l)` so that you are not recreating the same set over and over

```
l=[[1, 2], [3, 4], [4, 6], [2, 7], [3, 9]]
lf=[]
for li in map(set,l):
    for lfi in lf:
        if lfi & li:
            lfi |= li
            break
    else:
        lf.append(li)
```

Comment: Thansk also. I have to get used to optimizations like this

Answer (score 0):

```
l=[[1, 2], [3, 4], [4, 6], [2, 7], [3, 9]]
lf=[]
for li in l:
    for i, lfi in enumerate(lf):

        if lfi.intersection(set(li)):
            lfi=lfi.union(set(li))            
            lf[i] = lfi #You forgot to update the list
            break
    else:
        lf.append(set(li))
```